# bing map TestDataGenerator is undefined

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I tried the simplest example for bing maps in dynamic 365 CRM as a web resource.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">    
        <div class="map" id='mapId'></div>
        <div id='printoutPanel'></div>
    </div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        document.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (document.readyState == "complete") {
                loadMapScenario();
            }
        }

        function loadMapScenario() {
            var map = new window.parent.Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapId'), {
                credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key'
            });
            map.entities.push(window.parent.Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getPushpins(3, map.getBounds()));
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I do not have BingMapKey currently.

The map appears on the screen but without push pins since TestDataGenerator is undefined.
Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised the map even loaded. You need to have the Bing Maps V8 map script loaded in the same frame as the map, not in a parent window. Otherwise the map control won't be able to access all the resources it needs. Here is a modified version of your code that should work:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">    
        <div class="map" id='mapId'></div>
        <div id='printoutPanel'></div>
    </div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function loadMapScenario() {
        var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapId'), {
            credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key'
        });
        map.entities.push(Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getPushpins(3, map.getBounds()));
    }
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=loadMapScenario' async defer></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. 
That was confusing part, how my map was loaded without script. Since map was loaded I thought that CRM has map script included inside, and I do not need to call it. 
Now it is clear that was not the case.